# On Append (Essentially after something appears.)

Tags: jquery, append, delay

I'm trying to have a script run after a third party script adds some html, for the life of me I can't find a way to run script after something is added.

I've been trying using delay but it's not working.

```
$('#Form1').append('<div id="modal"></div>');

$('.AddToCartConfirmation > div > div').delay(1000).children('div, span').not(':first-child').wrapAll('<div class="orderInfo"></div>');

$('.AddToCartConfirmation > div > div').delay(1000).addClass('cartContents');

$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').delay(1000).append('<i class="fas fa-times"></i>');

$("#modal").click(function(){
    $('.ui-dialog.ui-corner-all.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-front.ui-draggable').css({'opcaity':'none','visibility':'hidden'});
    $('a[href="/Cart.html"] img').css('display','none');
    $(this).css({'opcaity':'none','visibility':'hidden'});
});
```

Comment: please, be more specific, I can't understand your goal here. You want something like a observer that keeps checking if some other scripts (that you don't control) add some html/nodes to your DOM, then executes something? What's the idea of `delay`?

Comment: You misspelled opacity a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Why it's not working?
If the problem has to do with timing between the external script do it's thing and you do yours you can use `setInterval()` to periodically check if the html added by the external scrpt exits and do what you want.

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var element = $('#element_id_added_by_external_script');
  if (element) {
    // code to add class, etc...
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 500);
```